# AVCapturePhotoOutput with 60 fps and flash on causes image to be over brightened

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice, avcapture

When using AVCapturePhotoOutput with flashMode On and AVCaptureDevice with minimum frame rate set to 60 fps results in an image that is very over brightened. Using the same configuration with 30 fps results in a correct image.  I have tried many AVCapturePhotoSettings but have not found any that work. This may just be a bug in iOS but wondering if anyone has any advice.

```
 let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
 settings.flashMode = flashOn ? .on : .off
 settings.isAutoVirtualDeviceFusionEnabled = true
 settings.isAutoRedEyeReductionEnabled = true
 self.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
```

[image: This is with 60 fps]

[image: This is with 30 fps]